# Looking for same function of if-statement, but faster

Tags: python, if-statement, matrix

I wrote some codes, but want to make it faster.

```
import numpy as np

test_unit = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
if set(np.unique(test_unit).astype(int)) >= set((1,2,3)):
    print('True')
```

What I want to do is writing the if-statement that if elements of matrix have (1 AND 2 AND 3, at least), then do a job. The test_unit in my real code is 2*2*2 matrix in about 400*400*200 matrix. If you guys don't mind, could you please give me some tips for this statement problem?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [`numpy.isin()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) and `all()`. This should be quite a bit faster than converting to a set:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [10, 11, 12, 13]])
sub = np.array([[1, 5], [6, 11]])
np.all(np.isin(sub, arr))
# True

sub = np.array([[1, 5], [6, 101]])
np.all(np.isin(sub, arr))
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a few performance tests and using any() with a list comprehension seems to be faster than np.isin() or set operations

```
N = 1000000
test_unit = np.arange(N)
values    = [N-2, N//2,10000] # will return True

all(v in test_unit for v in values) # 100 times: 0.1501
all(np.isin(values,test_unit))      # 100 times: 3.0908
set(values).issubset(test_unit)     # 100 times: 8.4157

noValues    = [-1,-2,-3] # will return False 

all(v in test_unit for v in noValues) # 100 times: 0.0545
all(np.isin(noValues,test_unit))      # 100 times: 2.9616
set(noValues).issubset(test_unit)     # 100 times: 8.680
```